# Error in x%%2 : non-numeric argument to binary operator

Tags: r

The following code is producing the error

> "Error in x%%2 : non-numeric argument to binary operator" in R.

Code:

```
oddeven <- function()
{
  x <- as.integer(readline(prompt = "insert number : "))

  if((x %% 2) == 0)
  {
    print("Even")
  }
  else
  {
    print("Odd")
  }
}

oddeven()
```

Please explain where is the actual error?

Comment: you're code seems to work OK, what input are you using to get the error?

Comment: I tried "as.numeric" instead of "as.integer". now its working fine.